# Forward email to pipe in ispcp

Tags: php, email, pipe

Can I forward email to pipe (somefile.php) in ISPCP like in Cpanel?

I'm using [similar script](http://harrybailey.com/2009/02/send-or-pipe-an-email-to-a-php-script/) on my test server, but client has ISPCP and he can't activate this:

1. ‘Email Management Tools -> Default E-mail account’,
2. chose the new subdomain from the dropdown list,
3. clicked ‘Advanced Options’,
4. selected the radio button for ‘Pipe to a Program’